# How do I stop audio in a different scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created an Object with an audio source that plays over 10 scenes (using DontDestroyOnLoad). After that scene I want to stop the music. Can anyone help me please? Thanks!

Comment: If the scene is a "different" one, it has not been loaded yet. So, saying that you want to stop sound in it is a bit nonsense. Can you please clarify it a bit? Or you just want to stop the AudioSource of that object when a particular scene is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create singleton class and play or stop from any class you want.
Create game object for sound manager and use this script on gameObject.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SoundManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public AudioSource musicSource;
    public static SoundManager instance = null;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = this;
        else if (instance != this)
            Destroy (gameObject);

        DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
    }

    public void PlayMusic(AudioClip clip)//We don't need Play for your problem.
    {
        musicSource.clip = clip;
        musicSource.Play ();
    }

    public void StopMusic(AudioClip clip)
    {
        musicSource.clip = clip;
        musicSource.Stop ();
    }
}
```

For example;

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public AudioClip mainTheme;

    public void NextLevel(int level)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel (level);

        if (level > 10)
            SoundManager.instance.StopMusic (mainTheme);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the thought in my comment above is correct, you can do this (in a script of the object having the AudioSource):

```
if (Application.loadedLevel == 11){    /*11 is an example*/
      GetComponent<AudioSource>().Stop();
}
```